# How to create solr cores with separate schemas

Tags: solr, schema

In my local environment, I am trying to create 2 different solr cores (product and popularity) with separate schemas. Loading the schema for the first core (product) works fine. However, when I try to load the schema for the second core (popularity), it ends up giving me the schema for both cores combined
e.g.

- Product Schema defined by me: sku, rating, price
- Product Schema loaded into solr: sku, rating, price
- Popularity Schema define by me: popularity_a, popularity_b
- Popularity schema loaded into solr: sku, rating, price, popularity_a, popularity_b

API Requests:

1. http://solr:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=product&instanceDir=product&configSet=managed-base&schema=schema.xml
2. http://solr:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=popualrity&instanceDir=product_&configSet=managed-base&schema=schema.xml
3. http://solr:8983/solr/product/schema (POST request with product.json schema)
4. http://solr:8983/solr/popularity/schema (POST request with popularity.json schema)

Comment: I see both the cores are using the same configset and schema file.
You need to provide different (either create a separate folder with different name and try)

Comment: you are providing the same config and schema file for both core. You have changed the core name and instanceDir only

Comment: In api request 3 and 4, I am sending the relevant schema as json file. Why does the schema.xml in the query parameters matter in this case?

Comment: Since you're using the same configSet, your schemas end up modifying the same configSet. If you don't want your changes to affect a shared configset, use separate configsets (or don't use a configset at all). Configsets are _shared configuration of collections or cores_, so when you modify them, you modify them for all the cores.

Comment: So I tried to create a separate configSet: `http://solr:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=product&instanceDir=product&configSet=config-product&schema=schema.xml` but I get the following error:
```
"msg":"Error CREATEing SolrCore \'product\': Unable to create core [product] Caused by: Could not load configuration from directory /var/solr/data/configsets/config-product"
```

Comment: are you running the solr in standalone mode or cloude mode? if cloud then switch to standalone mode in order to use the solr api. Solr API should be used only when solr started in standalone mode.

Comment: standalone mode